# How to read values of "JRXML Properties" dynamically/programatically?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jasper-reports

I got one problem that really need your helps. I'm in charge of creating an application. The application got some requirements as bellow:

1. Read *.jrxml (JasperReport xml) file.
2. Need to record any object's properties. For example, TextField has Font-Size, Name, etc.
3. Save them as the spec document. (see picture)

   [image]

The problem here is how to read objects with its properties dynamically; since different report(*.jrxml) has different xml format. Any ideas? Please help...

And here is what I already have tried:

1. JRXML Code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" 
         name="number-to-words" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" 
         rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e37ef9d7-03e0-4cf0-aa3e-ddc6a4434211">
   <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.9090909090909091"/>
   <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
   <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
   <queryString>
      <![CDATA[select freight from orders]]>
   </queryString>
   <field name="freight" class="java.lang.Long">
       <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
   </field>
   <background>
      <band splitType="Stretch"/>
   </background>
   <title>
      <band height="47" splitType="Stretch">
          <staticText>
              <reportElement uuid="cb175252-6939-4c44-972a-424c7cd71957" x="235" y="27" width="100" height="20"/>
              <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                  <font size="14"/>
               </textElement>
               <text><![CDATA[Static text]]></text>
          </staticText>
     </band>
   </title>
   <pageHeader>
     <band splitType="Stretch"/>
   </pageHeader>
   <columnHeader>
   <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
       <staticText>
           <reportElement uuid="67d8b9b6-5f01-41ac-9a2a-ced60ebcae41" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="21"/>
           <box leftPadding="4">
               <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
           </box>
           <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
               <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
           </textElement>
           <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
       </staticText>
       <staticText>
           <reportElement uuid="82d78d65-6828-4a64-b3b3-69e5a4aea356" x="85" y="0" width="470" height="21"/>
           <box leftPadding="4">
               <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
           </box>
           <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
               <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
           </textElement>
           <text><![CDATA[As words]]></text>
       </staticText>
   </band>
   </columnHeader>
   <detail>
   <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
       <textField>
           <reportElement uuid="ee38dfd7-d417-4fe6-bb99-130c05074fca" x="0" y="0" width="85" height="21"/>
           <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="5">
               <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
           </box>
           <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
               <font isBold="true"/>
           </textElement>
           <textFieldExpression><![CDATA['$' + ($F{freight}+1000).toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
       <textField>
           <reportElement uuid="b78301fb-10d4-4bd6-becb-9223c7de16f6" x="85" y="0" width="470" height="21"/>
           <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="5">
               <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
               <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
           </box>
           <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
               <font isBold="true"/>
           </textElement>
           <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new src.com.NumberToWord().ConvertNumber($F{freight}+1000)+ " Dollars"]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
   </band>
   </detail>
   <columnFooter>
      <band splitType="Stretch"/>
   </columnFooter>
   <pageFooter>
      <band splitType="Stretch"/>
   </pageFooter>
   <summary>
      <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
   </summary>
   </jasperReport>
   ```
2. Java Code:

   ```
   try{
       File xmlFile = new File("jrxml.jrxml");
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
       Document document = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
       document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

       Element element = (Element) document.getDocumentElement();
       NodeList nodeList = element.getChildNodes();

       for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
          Node node = nodeList.item(i);
          if(node instanceof Element){
              Element child = (Element) node;
              String tagName = child.getTagName();
              System.out.println(tagName);
          } 

       }
   }
   catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. Result: what it had read.

   ```
   property
   property
   property
   queryString
   field
   background
   title
   pageHeader
   columnHeader
   detail
   columnFooter
   pageFooter
   summary
   ```

Comment: I think you should use one of XML parsers for this purpose. refer this link for SAX parser : (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html)

Comment: use can refer schema of jrxml here : [HTML format](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/schema.reference.html) or [XML format](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd)

Comment: I already tried your solution.
It's working. However, I got another problem.
Can you help me? please check bellow post.